# Como utilizar runOnUiThread()

Tags: android, método

estou estudando a utilização de Threads, aSynkTasks e Handlers e me deparei com este metodo,  runOnUiThread()

- De que forma este método se torna um processo repetitivo a ponto de substituir o handler?De que modo
  funciona este método?
- Gostaria de entender o funcionamento desse método e qual a
  necessidade de implementar  Runnable() dentro deste método como neste
  exemplo:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable())
public void run(){
// alguma coisa}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Definição do método:**

> "Executa a ação especificada na Thread de UI. Se o Thread atual for o
>   Thread da UI, então a ação será executada imediatamente. Se o Thread
>   atual não for da UI, a ação é lançada na fila de eventos."

Então vamos lá:

- **De que forma este método se torna um processo repetitivo a ponto de substituir o handler?De que modo funciona este método?**

Acredito que não substitui o `Handler`, pois eles possuem funcionalidades diferentes!

O `runOnUiThread`, envia um `Runnable` para ser executado na Thread da UI, enquanto o `Handler`, executa um `Runnable` em um tempo futuro (pré definido) ou executa este `Runnable` em uma `Thread` diferente (não apenas da UI como o `runOnUiThread`).

- **Gostaria de entender o funcionamento desse método e qual a necessidade de implementar Runnable() dentro deste método**

Acredito que a definição acima, explique o seu funcionamento!

Agora vamos a definição do `Runnable` :

> A interface Runnable deve ser implementada por qualquer classe cujas
>   instâncias sejam destinadas a serem executadas por um Thread.

Usamos o `Runnable` para encapsular e enviar o código que queremos transferir para ser executada em outra `Thread`.

[Documentação do método runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

[Documentação da Classe Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

[Documentação da interface Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

Comment: otima explicação :) é que no exemplo do livro que eu vi ele utiliza como um substituto do handler... de modo que se ele chamar este metodo nao precisa de um handler pras outras coisas... obrigado!

Comment: Então, por isso eu **acredito** que não substitui, o Handler tem várias utilizações, e uma dela é bem parecida com que o método 'runOnUiThread' faz!